# I can't run multiple c++ files in VS code WSL

Tags: c++, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I can't run multiple c++ files with VS code WSL and here is my task.json:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
```

I tried to change "${file}" to "${*.cpp}" and "${**.cpp}" but neither worked for me

Comment: With `"${file}"` you only build the *current* file being edited. Which is the default. I suggest you look into build-systems like `make` or meta-build/-project systems like CMake. Especially a system like CMake will make it very easy to create multi-file projects.

Comment: As a quick workaround, you need to list all individual source files (as separate arguments) for the compiler.

Comment: that tasks.json is only useful for single file projects. For more complex stuff, either use a build system like CMake (easy enough to set up for simple projects with no dependencies) or write your own Makefile